# How can I make a table of symbols with TeX?

Tags: tables

I have used the following command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage[final]{showexpl}
\begin{document}
 \begin{LTXexample}[pos=r,rframe=single,numbers=none,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,]
\xymatrix{A \ar[r]^f & B}
\xymatrix{A \ar@{^{(}->}[r]^f & B}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image]

but I'd prefer to create the following table:

[image]

Comment: I have run it with 'kile.

Comment: If there exists any alternative way please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xypic}

\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\linewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.3\linewidth}|}
\hline
  \centering Objetive {\footnotesize and} Input \par\footnotesize Commands to produce the diagrams  displayed on the right are as follows, respectively: &
   Output\par\footnotesize\itshape (what you get) 
 \tabularnewline\hline
  {\small The default case arrow:}\par
    \verb+\xymatrix{A \ar[r]^f & B}+  & $\xymatrix{A \ar[r]^f & B}$
 \tabularnewline\hline
  {\small Inclusion arrow:}\par
    \verb+\xymatrix{A \ar@{^{(}->}[r]^f & B}+  & $\xymatrix{A \ar@{^{(}->}[r]^f & B}$
 \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This avoids code duplication; you specify the code in the left column and say `\usecode` in the second column.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,xparse}
\usepackage{xypic}

\NewDocumentCommand{\code}{v}{%
  \gdef\usecode{$\scantokens{#1}$}%
  \texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table of the main \Xy{} constructs}

\centering
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{
  m{.6\columnwidth}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{.3\columnwidth}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{p{.6\columnwidth}}{\centering
  Objective {\footnotesize and} Input \par
   \footnotesize Commands to produce the diagrams displayed
   on the right are as follows, respectively:} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{.3\columnwidth}}{\centering
  Output\par\footnotesize\itshape (what you get)} \\
\midrule

The default case arrow:\newline
  \code{\xymatrix{A \ar[r]^f & B}}  & \usecode \\
\midrule

Inclusion arrow:\newline
\code{\xymatrix{A \ar@{^{(}->}[r]^f & B}}  & \usecode \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]